# i have a json objects in mongodb server and i want to show it in the textview of android what to do

Tags: java, android, mongodb

I'm storing a data from android studio into mongodb,storing the data is successful but retrieving is somewhat hard.

even though I find a way to read the data in mongodb it gives json objects in the server side.

I need a way to display that json objects into the textview of an android.

```
package com.example.prabhakaran.toiletfeedbacksystem;

import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase;
import org.bson.Document;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class readDB  {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    comments(args);
    feedback(args);
    neo_checklist(args);
    robin_checklist(args);

}

public static void comments(String[] args) {

    MongoClient client = new MongoClient("172.20.9.122", 28018);
    MongoDatabase database = client.getDatabase("raji");
    MongoCollection<Document> collection = database
            .getCollection("testcollection");

    List<Document> documents = collection.find().into(
            new ArrayList<Document>());

    for(Document document : documents){
        System.out.println(document);
    }
}

public static void feedback(String[] args) {

    MongoClient client = new MongoClient("172.20.9.122", 28018);
    MongoDatabase database = client.getDatabase("raji");
    MongoCollection<Document> collection = database
            .getCollection("Comments");

    List<Document> documents = collection.find().into(
            new ArrayList<Document>());

    for(Document document : documents){
        System.out.println(document);
    }
}

public static void neo_checklist(String[] args) {

    MongoClient client = new MongoClient("172.20.9.122", 28018);
    MongoDatabase database = client.getDatabase("raji");
    MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("neo");

    List<Document> documents = collection.find().into(new ArrayList<Document>());

    for(Document document : documents){
        System.out.println(document);
    }
}

public static void robin_checklist(String[] args) {

    MongoClient client = new MongoClient("172.20.9.122", 28018);
    MongoDatabase database = client.getDatabase("raji");
    MongoCollection<Document> collection = database
            .getCollection("robin");

    List<Document> documents = collection.find().into(
            new ArrayList<Document>());

    for(Document document : documents){
        System.out.println(document);
    }
}
}
```

Output

> Document{ {_id=5c5020c08d5509385e1ac8f4, Value=robin, done=clean
>   toilet_bowl, Created_Date=Tue Jan 29 15:15:36 IST 2019} }

I have this type of data in the run window on android studio,but I want to have those data in the android app in textview or something.

so assist me in this issue,Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look into JSON Parsing for your problem. Your output is basically a Document object. You might need to convert it to JSON and perform the parsing.

Comment: can you help me with on how to convert that document object into JSON.